# How to center three DIVS with other HTML tags inside one parent DIV

Tags: html, css

I have the following ASP.net page with some CMS Content Block:

```
<div class="section group" style="background: #CCCCCC; overflow: auto;">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    <CMS:ContentBlock ID="ContentBlock5" runat="server" CssClass="test2" DefaultContentID="638" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    <CMS:ContentBlock ID="ContentBlock6" runat="server" CssClass="test2" DefaultContentID="638" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    <CMS:ContentBlock ID="ContentBlock7" runat="server" CssClass="test2" DefaultContentID="638" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Which generates the following HTML source:

```
<div class="section group" style="background: #CCCCCC; overflow: auto;">
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    <div id="ContentBlock5" class="test2">
    <p align="center"><span class="info" align="left"><strong>Regular Hours:</strong><br />Monday&#160;- Friday: 8am - 9pm<br />Saturday&#160;&amp; Sunday: 9am - 5pm</span> <br /><span class="info" align="left"><a title="Most Insurance Plans Accepted" href="/participating_insurance.aspx?id=473">Most Insurance Plans Accepted</a><br />914-848-5600</span></p>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    <div id="ContentBlock6" class="test2">
    <p align="center"><span class="info" align="left"><strong>Regular Hours:</strong><br />Monday&#160;- Friday: 8am - 9pm<br />Saturday&#160;&amp; Sunday: 9am - 5pm</span> <br /><span class="info" align="left"><a title="Most Insurance Plans Accepted" href="/participating_insurance.aspx?id=473">Most Insurance Plans Accepted</a><br />914-848-5650</span></p>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    <div id="ContentBlock7" class="test2">
    <p align="center"><span class="info" align="left"><strong>Regular Hours:</strong><br />Monday&#160;- Friday: 8am - 9pm<br />Saturday&#160;&amp; Sunday: 9am - 5pm</span> <br /><span class="info" align="left"><a title="Most Insurance Plans Accepted" href="/participating_insurance.aspx?id=473">Most Insurance Plans Accepted</a><br />914-848-5650</span></p>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS to display it:

```
        .test2
        {
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(238,146,85,1);
        }
            .test2 p
            {
                text-align: left;
            }
.test1 p {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.setP p
{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.group:after {
    clear:both;
}
.group {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 {
    width: 100%;
}
.span_2_of_3 {
    width: 66.1%;
}
.span_1_of_3 {
    width: 32.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col { 
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span_3_of_3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span_2_of_3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span_1_of_3 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Output to the end user is this:

[image]

As the image shows the three DIVS are not centered.

How can I modify the CSS so it is always centered regardless of screen size.

Update:

[image]

Comment: @GolezTrol - Almost the same title too... lol

Comment: Yeah, I found it by Googling for the title. It wasn't the only duplicate by the way. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `text-align: center` to the parent of the divs... In this case, the `section` one:

```
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also, remove the float from the `col` divs, and make them inline:

```
.col {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1%;
}
```

[**Example JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lry4z15m/)

Comment: This is great except one issue try to drag the window to the right, right before they are vertical. The third box goes on to the second line. How to ensure it always stays in one line until 480px?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge - Use `white-space: nowrap` on the section: http://jsfiddle.net/Lry4z15m/1/

Answer (score 2):

Setting `display: inline-block;` to the **content block** you get **100% of content width**.

Then adding `text-align: center;` to it's **parent**, center **content** to all dimensions:

```
.test2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.test2 p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ob1dr37h/

Answer (score 2):

change `float:left;` to `display: inline-block` on `.col` and then add `text-align: center` to `.section`.

Comment: Only one problem with that is the third box goes to the next line which I am trying to prevent, I updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: adjust your margins then, `display: inline-block` will add a natural space of around 1 or 2 pixels. But unlike floating, it will keep your elements centered always

Answer (score 0):

From first issue I see that you are doing :

1. Combination of css and attributes on html elements 
   what is leading to confusion.
2. You have p aligned center and span aligned left. For what reason?

Try to use a padding css property. Let p tags pad from div tags and css display-inline with text align cener.

If html standards are not requirments you can always wrap around p tag a center tag.

Comment: I will be moving the attributes to the CSS once I have it set up correctly. Align left is for the text inside the inner div and align center is to center the three DIVS